# how to manage repeated tags in xml with xsl style sheet

Tags: xml, xslt

hi every body i have a facing a little problem here...
if suppose i have receiving a file format of xml in that some block will be there under the blocks tags will be coming for some blocks tags will not be repeated and in some blocks tags will be repeated
ex:
 *

```
           <block3>
        <tag>
            <name>113</name>
            <value>FINANCIAL</value>
        </tag>

    </block3>
             <block4>

        <tag>
            <name>32A</name>
            <value>051028EUR9000,71</value>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <name>32A</name>
            <value>051028EUR7000,71</value>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <name>33B</name>
            <value>EUR9000,71</value>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <name>33B</name>
            <value>EUR7000,71</value>
        </tag>
                     <tag>
            <name>71A</name>
            <value>OUR</value>
        </tag>
    </block4>
                   <xsl:for-each select ="block3/tag[name = '113']">
            <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        </xsl:for-each>,
                   <xsl:for-each select ="block4/tag[name = '32A']">
  <xsl:value-of select="(translate(substring(value,10),',','.'))"/>,<xsl:text/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select ="block4/tag[name = '33B']">
  <xsl:value-of select="(translate(substring(value,1),',','.'))"/>,<xsl:text/>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

*

i have prepared xsl style sheet bellow like this

Output :

if no tags repeatability means

FINANCIAL, 9000.71,EUR9000.71

but here xml tags are repeating in inside the block so i would like to expecting the result like

FINANCIAL, 9000.71,EUR9000.71

FINANCIAL, 7000.71,EUR7000.71

Comment: hello can any please give me some suggestions!!!

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, you are looking for a way to output the same data from all `<block>` tags?

Are you able to change the XML structure? It would help if it wasn't block3 and block4, but just multiple  tags. Then you could do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This template will match all `<tag>` tags. Then you simply apply templates over the blocks/tags.

`<xsl:apply-templates select="block/tag"/>`

This line will carry out the process on every tag that is a child of a block tag.

But if you can't change the structure of the XML simply keep the template and do:

```
`<xsl:apply-templates select="block3/tag"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="block4/tag"/>`
```

etc for each blockN.

In my opinion (from what I have been taught) using apply-templates (although more difficult to understand as a beginner than for-each) is much better than using loops in XSL as it is a template based language.

Does this help? Your question wasn't very clear.

Comment: thanks for replying me ... previous i have recieved a xml which was having each individual tags in each block now what is my problem is for some few tags generation purpose they cant make entire xml again so they are generating in a single block with repeatability of tags so i have given example for when tags are not repeated if i use above code xslt i can achive output like as FINANCIAL,9000.71,7000.71,EUR900.71,EUR7000.71 like that i was getting but i need output like FINANCIAL,9000.71,EUR900.71 and next line FINANCIAL,7000.71,EUR7000.71

Comment: @pubby sorry I'm guessing English isn't your first language? What is the context you are in within your document when you are trying the for-each? there is only one block3/tag[name="113"] so that will only be outputted once when you call your code. Could you show more of your XML that you are working with?

Comment: just have a look at this *<swift>
  <message></block3>
             <block4>

        <tag>
            <name>32A</name>
            <value>051028EUR9000,71</value>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <name>32A</name>
            <value>051028EUR7000,71</value>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <name>33B</name>
            <value>EUR9000,71</value>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <name>33B</name>
            <value>EUR7000,71</value>
        </tag>                 
    </block4>
</message>
</swift> yes block data will come only once so we need take again makerequired